# Computer experiences occasional framerate stutters with 1000hz mouse polling rate

Tags: bios, performance, mouse, lag

I am experiencing framerate stutters when I have my mouse polling rate set to 1000hz. The framerate stutters mostly disappears when I use my mouse at 500hz but my PC should not be having framerate stutters because my mouse polling rate is set to 1000hz. I notice no spikes in CPU or GPU usage on task managers when these framerate stutters happen. I have already tried the following:

- updating my BIOS to the most recent version on my [motherboard website](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B350-GAMING-PRO-CARBON/support): 7B00v1L2(Beta version)
- disabling Global C states in BIOS. I've read on other sources to disable the C3 state but MSI BIOS only has this option.
- disabling Hyper-V and virtualization
- having my monitors run at native/reccomended resolution
- updating Windows/checking for Windows updates
- updating my graphics drivers
- updating my mouse drivers and firmware
- reinstalling windows mouse driver
- setting my power plan to high performance
- trying another mouse at 1000hz
- uninstalling all mouse software
- installing the recommended mouse software for the current plugged in mouse (only the software for the current mouse is installed)
- disabling GeForce overlay and closing Discord completely
- turning off all my monitors except the main one
- unplugging every USB device except my mouse (no unknown devices in device manager)
- rebooting my PC

Here are my PC specs:

- OS: Windows 10 Enterprise 22H2 19045.3324
- Motherboard: MSI B350 GAMING PRO CARBON
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X 3.70 GHz
- GPU: Nvidia 1070ti
- RAM: 16 GB
- Mouse 1: Corsair DARK CORE PRO RGB
- Mouse 2: Logitech G Pro X Superlight

Some extra things I noticed:

- when using a mouse polling rate tester, the mouse polling rate will sometimes go above 1000hz when I have the mouse set to 1000hz
- when using 500hz there is sometimes also sometimes framerate stutters but much less frequent and sometimes hardly noticeable

I am almost certain I have tried every possible solution that I have found at this point except reformatting my PC which is not possible for me to do due to the amount of on-going dev projects I have going on. Also note that I have the LTSB version of Windows 10 so I do not have the option to update to Windows 11. I have had this issue bother me for almost 3 months now. I did not have these framerate stutters before and one day it just started but I do not remember when or if it was directly after a Windows Update. How can I fix this issue? I have been trying to fix it for almost a month now with no avail.

Comment: not possible for me to do due to the amount of on-going dev    ... So what is wrong with the default Mouse settings?

Comment: I would like to avoid a reformat overall just because of the hassle it comes with. The mouse by default is 1000hz. I would like to use 1000hz and the issue I want to resolve is why my mouse is lagging my PC on 1000hz.

Comment: I would try a lower rate. I did some online tests and 500 Hz or somewhat less works fine. Seems a reasonable trade off to avoid reinstalling Windows

Comment: Yes but the issue and my question is to not lag when using 1000hz. My PC should not lag at 1000hz with those specs. The whole point of me asking this is to also avoid switching to 500hz and stay at 1000hz just without the lag.

Comment: The fastest human reflexes are on the order of 10 ms, equivalent to a polling rate of 100/s. If the mouse seems to lag, likely the system is being *overloaded* with far too much data.

Comment: I don't really understand the point of these comments. I know many people who have PC specs worse or similar to mine who do not get lag spikes on 1000hz or even 2000hz. Not to mention the Intellimouse existed in the 2000s and ran at well over 1000hz with no issues on computers at the time. I'm not looking for suggestions to lower my mouse HZ or someone to lecture me on human reaction speeds. I'm looking for a solution to an issue I should not be having.